# How to override the rollup output.format setting in vite?

Tags: vite, rollupjs

I'm trying to solve the Vite build error I get:

> RollupError: Invalid value "iife" for option "output.format" - UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for code-splitting builds.

The file name reported with this error points to
my web worker code, so I assumed that this setting belongs to the `worker` section in vite.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import preact from "@preact/preset-vite";
import basicSsl from "@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl";

import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        preact(),
        basicSsl(),
    ],
    server: {
        port: 3001,
        https: true,
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
                NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
            ],
        },
    },
    worker: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                format: "esm",
            },
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [
                // Enable rollup polyfills plugin
                // used during production bundling
                rollupNodePolyFill(),
            ],
            output: {
                format: "esm",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Additionally, I set the output format in the build rollup options. However, neither of the two settings are applied and I still get the said error.

What is the correct way to change the rollup output format setting in Vite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker output format must be specified directly in the worker config key, not its rollup options:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import preact from "@preact/preset-vite";
import basicSsl from "@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl";

import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        preact(),
        basicSsl(),
    ],
    server: {
        port: 3001,
        https: true,
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
                NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
            ],
        },
    },
    worker: {
        format: "es",
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [
                // Enable rollup polyfills plugin
                // used during production bundling
                rollupNodePolyFill(),
            ],
            output: {
                format: "esm",
            },
        },
    },
});
```